# Array of references that share an Arc

Tags: memory, rust, lifetime

This one's kind of an open ended design question I'm afraid.

Anyway: I have a big two-dimensional array of stuff. This array is mutable, and is accessed by a bunch of threads. For now I've just been dealing with this as a `Arc<Mutex<Vec<Vec<--owned stuff-->>>>`, which has been fine.

The problem is that `stuff` is about to grow considerably in size, and I'll want to start holding references rather than complete structures. I could do this by inverting everything and going to `Vec<Vec<Arc<Mutex>>`, but I feel like that would be a ton of overhead, especially because each thread would need a complete copy of the grid rather than a single `Arc/Mutex`.

What I want to do is have this be an array of references, but somehow communicate that the items being referenced all live long enough according to a single top-level Arc or something similar. Is that possible?

As an aside, is `Vec` even the correct data type for this? For the grid in particular I really want a large, fixed-size block of memory that will live for the entire length of the program once it's initialized, and has a lot of reference locality (along either dimension.) Is there something else/more specialized I should be using?

EDIT:Giving some more specifics on my code (away from home so this is rough):

**What I want:**

- Outer scope initializes a bunch of `T`s and somehow collectively ensures they live long enough (that's the hard part)
- Outer scope initializes a `grid :Something<Vec<Vec<&T>>>` that stores references to the `T`s
- Outer scope creates a bunch of threads and passes `grid` to them
- Threads dive in and out of some sort of (problable RW) lock on `grid`, reading the `T`sand changing the `&T`s in the process.

**What I have:**

- Outer thread creates a `grid: Arc<RwLock<Vector<Vector<T>>>>`
- `Arc::clone(& grid)`s are passed to individual threads
- Read-heavy threads mostly share the lock and sometimes kick each other out for the writes.

The only problem with this is that the grid is storing actual `T`s which might be problematically large. (Don't worry too much about the RwLock/thread exclusivity stuff, I think it's perpendicular to the question unless something about it jumps out at you.)

**What I don't want to do:**

- Top level creates a bunch of `Arc<Mutex<T>>` for individual `T`
- Top level creates a `grid : Vec<Vec<Arc<Mutex>>> and passes it to threads

The problem with that is that I worry about the size of `Arc/Mutex` on every grid element (I've been going up to `2000x2000` so far and may go larger). Also while the threads would lock each other out less (only if they're actually looking at the same square), they'd have to pick up and drop locks way more as they explore the array, and I think that would be worse than my current `RwLock` implementation.

Comment: Do items within the array need to be mutable?

Comment: Sort of but not really. I need to change the refences stored in each square. The refences will point to things that may need to refer to changing data but I can handle that other ways (at worst I could have immutable keys that point into mutable maps stored independently.)

Comment: Is this "large, fixed-size block of memory" immutable data, or does it need to be mutable?

Comment: @cdhowie It needs to be mutable. It's a grid representing the map of a changing simulation.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html)? As it is currently, I'm afraid this question is not a good fit for SO. We need to see your code.

Comment: What Chayim said -- it's also possible that `Box::leak()` could work, for example, but hard to say without seeing a concrete example.

Comment: Is your data comprised entirely of integers? If so you may be able to simply use `Atomic*` types to allow mutation via immutable reference, and avoid the need for a mutex at all?

Comment: @cameron1024 It isn't all numeric, but also I'm not clear what the advantage of that would be?

Comment: A `Mutex` is one way to go from immutable -> mutable references, but there are others. Specifically `Atomic*` types provide methods which mutate the underlying data, while only needing a shared reference. If you're concerned about the overhead of many `Mutex`es, `Atomic*`s are much lower overhead. For example, something like an `Arc<[[AtomicU64; N]; M]>` could achieve something similar to what you describe

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I need to work out the specifics, but I feel like scoped threads and some lifetime annotations could do it - something like `Arc<Mutex<Vec<Vec< 'lifetime &T>>>>` where `lifetime` outlivesthe thread? (I haven't dealt with explicit lifetimes yet, so there might be some holes there)

Comment: @cameron1024 Okay - I imagine that would give a performance boost, but not as much as I'm looking for? Like my feeling is that I should be able to get away with a single top-level lock rather than individual locks on every element. (Though, individual locks would let the threads cooperate more... I left this part out cause it feels aside to my question, but each thread does thousands of reads before a single write, so I'm currently getting away with a single `RwLock` and hoping the simultaneous reads dominate the exclusive writes.)

Comment: Yeah the answer to this question will probably depend quite a bit on what your program is actually doing. In general, wrapping a large data structure in a `Mutex` and sharing between threads has potential to cause lock contention issues, which can often be alleviated by per-element locking. Acquiring a lock has some runtime overhead, so the more locks you have, the more time you spend getting and releasing locks. Is this worth the increased parallelism? Only benchmarks will tell. I'd recommend trying both, and benchmarking withthe  `criterion` crate

Comment: `Vec<Vec<Foo>>` is usually a poor choice for a rectangular grid. Much better to use a single `Vec<Foo>` of length `width*height` and accessing individual items through `v[row * width + col]` or `v[col * height + row]`. This will be faster, improve cache locality and waste less memory.

Comment: @Jmb I've been trying to figure out more on the vector stuff. One concern I have is how lazy the code is about initialization - like, if I say `let mut v : Vec<Option<SomeLargeStruct>> = vec![None, 9999999]`, will it claim enough space to keep everything constant or will it try to be compact at first and then spend lots of time re-arranging as things fill out? (In my case the vectors start out sparse then fill in substantially)

Comment: I assume you meant `vec![None; 9999999]` and it will allocate enough space for everything up front (unless and until you `push` a new element to the vector).

Answer (score 0):

Let me start of by your "aside" question, as I feel it's the one that can be answered:

> As an aside, is Vec even the correct data type for this? For the grid in particular I really want a large, fixed-size block of memory that will live for the entire length of the program once it's initialized, and has a lot of reference locality (along either dimension.) Is there something else/more specialized I should be using?

The [documenation of `std::vec::Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#288) specifies that the layout is essentially a pointer with size information. That means that any `Vec<Vec<T>>` is a pointer to a densely packed array of pointers to densely packed arrays of `T`s. So if block of memory means a contiguous block to you, then no, `Vec<Vec<T>>` cannot give that you. If that is part of your requirements, you'd have to deal with a datatype (let's call it `Grid`) that is basically a `(pointer, n_rows, n_columns)` and define for yourself if the layout should be row-first or column-first.

The next part is that if you want different threads to mutate e.g. columns/rows of your grid at the same time, `Arc<Mutex<Grid>>` won't cut it, but you already figured that out. You should get clarity whether you can split your problem such that each thread can only operate on rows **OR** columns. Remember that if any thread holds a `&mut Row`, no other thread must hold a `&mut Column`: There will be an overlapping element, and it will be very easy for you to create a data races. If you can assign a static range of of rows to a thread (e.g. thread 1 processes rows 1-3, thread 2 processes row 3-6, etc.), that should make your life considerably easier. To get into "row-wise" processing if it doesn't arise naturally from the problem, you might consider breaking it into e.g. a row-wise step, where all threads operate on rows only, and then a column-wise step, possibly repeating those.

#### Speculative starting point

I would suggest that your main thread holds the `Grid` struct which will almost inevitably be implemented with some unsafe methods, e.g. `get_row(usize)`, `get_row_mut(usize)` if you can split your problem into rows/colmns or `get(usize, usize)` and `get(usize, usize)` if you can't. I cannot tell you what exactly these should return, but they might even be custom references to `Grid`, which:

- can only be obtained when the usual borrowing rules are fulfilled (e.g. by blocking the thread until any other `GridRefMut` is dropped)
- implement `Drop` such that you don't create a deadlock

Every thread holds a `Arc<Grid>`, and can draw cells/rows/columns for reading/mutating out of the grid as needed, while the grid itself keeps book of references being created and dropped.

The downside of this approach is that you basically implement a runtime borrow-checker yourself. It's tedious and probably error-prone. You should browse crates.io before you do that, but your problem sounds specific enough that you might not find a fitting solution, let alone one that's sufficiently documented.

Comment: So this has some helpful stuff, but there are a few things I should have clarified. First, the issue with the single `<Arc<MutexVec<...>>>` isn't that they're excluding each other, it's how to fill it with references rather than raw data, due to borrow semantics stuff. (I can guarantee the entire `Arc` lives long enough, but I'm not sure how to do that for stuff referenced *inside* it.)

As for the multiple threads accessing it simultaneously, that's currently handled okay with an `RwLock` - each thread has thousands of read to a single write.